# how to dismiss a popovercontroler from anotherviewcontroler

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

i have a barbutton in the main menu..tapping that button will show a popoveontroller,,,called bookselectionview,,,it consists of tableview ,,when i tap the cel it navigate to the another view controller inside the popover,,seondview consists of buttons,,when i tap any button it navigate to third view controller inside the popover controller...all works fineee..but my problem is,,i want to dismiss this popoverontroller when i tap any button in the thirdview...and must navigate to main view ..now it shows the main view inside the popoverontrollerr..i had tried many things,,but nothing helps me...my code for this is...

in my bar button of the main view i put this code

```
  BookSelectionview* popoverContent = [[BookSelectionview alloc]
                                         init];    
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:popoverContent] autorelease];

    popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover =
    CGSizeMake(500, 800);

    self.popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                              initWithContentViewController:navigationController];

    [self.popup presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(348, 0, 0, 0)
                                            inView:self.view
                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                          animated:YES];
```

then in my bookselectionview controller i put this ode in my tableview did select metho

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


 ChapterSelectionView *detailViewController = [[ChapterSelectionView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChapterSelectionView" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover =
    CGSizeMake(500, 600);

    //detailViewController.firstString = firstString;
    // ...
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    detailViewController.selectedIndex=indexPath.row;
    appDelegate.selectedBookIndex=indexPath.row;
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

    [detailViewController release];

}
```

in my seconview(chapterselectionview) i put this codee in the button cilk

```
-(void)ButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(spinBeginchapterselection) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

        VersusSelectionView *detailViewController = [[VersusSelectionView alloc] initWithNibName:@"VersusSelectionView" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover =
    CGSizeMake(500,600);

    detailViewController.selectedChapter=[sender.titleLabel.text intValue];
    appDelegate.selectedChapterIndex=[sender.titleLabel.text intValue];
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

    [detailViweController relese];
```

then in my third view that is verseviewcontroller i put this code to navigate to main view(parallelReaviewcontroller)here i need to dismiss the popup....

```
-(void)ButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(spinBeginverseselection) toTarget:self withObject:nil];



    appDelegate.selectedBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:appDelegate.selectedBookIndex];
    appDelegate.selectedChapter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",appDelegate.selectedChapterIndex];
    appDelegate.selectedVerse = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[sender.titleLabel.text intValue]];
    [appDelegate reloadVerses];

        ParallelReadViewController *detailViewController = [[ParallelReadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ParallelReadViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

    [detailViewController release];
 please help me to solve this problem,,,thanks in advance.
```

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346207/multiple-views-navigation-in-uipopovercontroller/10930336#10930336